# Android start 160.000 AsnycTasks

Tags: android, azure, android-asynctask

For my master thesis I need to analyse iris recognition data. Therefore I have about 400 templates created. Each of this templates has to be compared to each other template, resulting in ~160.000 matching results.

Those results need to be uploaded to my Azure Easy Table. I really don't know where to start as the ThreadPoolExecutor cannot handle more than 128 Threads in parallel.

What is the correct approach to do something like this? Time is not really an issue.

This is my current approach:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mIrisEntries.size(); i++){
    match(i);
}

public void match(final int position) {
    IrisEntry inputEntry = mIrisEntries.get(position);

    // takes about 10ms
    List<IrisResult> results = mUSITHelper.matchEntries(inputEntry, mIrisEntries, this); 

    for (IrisResult s : results) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            mAzureTableManager.addIrisResult(s); // here the AsyncTask is started
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

This approach works for some time,. but then the system starts to kill all threads and uploading is cancelled.

Comment: How long does it take to process one of the 160,000 results? Or, if you prefer, how long would it take for you to process all 160,000 results, done one at a time?

Comment: By processing you mean the upload or the creation of one result? Matching of two templates takes about ~10 ms

Comment: "By processing you mean the upload or the creation of one result?" -- I don't know, as I do not know your app. Are you doing one Azure upload operation for *each* of the 160,000 matching results? Or are you doing one at the end of all 160,000 matches? Or something else (e.g., uploading in batches)?

Comment: Atm I am matching one resault to all others -> so I have an ArrayList of ~400 results. On those I was using a for loop to upload (bad idea). Then another for loop for iterating over the remaining templates

Comment: Edited my question with my current approach.

Comment: You can save save the 160,000 results to some datastucture (If the data generated is not huge) or a file and later this can be uploaded with a single API call.

Answer (score 1):

I do not completely follow all of what you describe in the question and comments.

However, at that amount of processing time (~30 minutes if I understood you), you need to use a foreground service, as otherwise your process may not survive that long. In that service, use your own `ThreadPoolExecutor`, with the number of threads in the pool tuned based on the number of CPU cores. Ideally, I would not post ~160,000 jobs to that executor, but rather 400, where each of those 400 jobs performs the work for one of your templates. The last job you post to the executor would do any final cleanup, plus stop the service.

Also, you may be able to halve your work. Suppose A and B are two of your templates. If comparing A to B is the same as comparing B to A, you do not need to do both comparisons. Your 400 templates expanding to ~160,000 jobs seems to imply that you are comparing A to B and B to A for all pairs.

Answer (score 0):

As @CommonsWare said, I think it's a good idea for reducing the number of upload request & the data size.

However, per my experience, I suggest that you need to try to [enable offline sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-offline-data) for your android app so that don't need to consider to the issue about uploading data asynchronously.

Hope it helps.